# Cannot Inject CSS through Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a Chrome Extension that would inject CSS on to the page when the Extension button is clicked.

The popup loads fine however the CSS cannot be injected.

**Manifest.json:**

```
{
  "name": "Flat Firemem",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Arranges the page properly in the dump.",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "logo.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": ["tabs", "<all_urls>", "file:///*"]
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style=''>
<head>
<script src='tester.js'></script>
</head>
<body style="width:400px; border: 2px solid black;background-color:LightGray;">
<div id='message'>Hello..!!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Style.css**

```
*
{
    float: none !important;
    position: static !important;
}

table, tbody, td, tfoot, th, thead, tr
{
    display: block !important;
}
```

**tester.js:**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
                           {file:"style.css"});
});
```

It would be of great help if someone figures what's wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`chrome.tabs.insertCSS`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-insertCSS) instead, as simple as that. Note that the tab id is optional:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.insertCSS({file:"style.css"});
});
```

Oh. Also, you need to use either a popup or a listener to `chrome.browserAction.onClicked`.
You can't use both, as the event is not fired while a popup is defined.

Two possible solutions:

1. Your code should instead go into background:

   ```
   {
     "name": "Flat Firemem",
     "version": "1.0",
     "manifest_version": 2,
     "description": "Arranges the page properly in the dump.",
     "browser_action": {
       "default_icon": "logo.png",
     },
     "background": {
       "scripts": ["tester.js"]
     },
     "permissions": ["tabs", "<all_urls>", "file:///*"]
   }
   ```
2. Or, you just call the code when popup appears:

   ```
   // tester.js: no need to listen to event
   chrome.tabs.insertCSS({file:"style.css"});
   ```

Of note: your permissions are a bit excessive for the task. Look into [`activeTab` permission](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab), and also note that `<all_urls>` permission includes `file:///` URLs.